# concatenate $http.post requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

How can I concatenate two $http (.post) requests, so that one is called after the other?
This is my function, which seems not working.

```
$scope.signup = function() {
    console.log("New user");   
    $http.post('/signup',{
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }).then(function success($http){
         return $http.post('api/userData/init'); //error
    }).then(function redirect($state){
        return $state.go('profile');
    });            

}
```

Comment: What's the error? You need a callback function on the second post - `.then(function success($http){...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `$http` in the first callback. The `then` function expects a function that takes the result of the http call as its argument. Try:

```
$scope.signup = function() {
    console.log("New user");   
    $http.post('/signup',{
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }).then(function(){
         return $http.post('api/userData/init'); 
    }).then(function (){
        return $state.go('profile');
    });            

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed it by just a notch

```
$scope.signup = function() {
    console.log("New user");   
    $http.post('/signup',{
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }).then(function(data){
        $http.post('api/userData/init').then(function(newData){
            $state.go('profile');
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you also can use $q Promises in calls explicitly:

```
//$q needs to be injected in the controller or service
   var q = $q.deffer();

   $http.post('/signup',{
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }).then(function(data){
        //on success
       q.resolve(data);
    }, function(){
        //on fail
        q.reject('Failed');
    });

    //second call after the first is done
    q.promise.then(function(firstCalldata){
        //if you need you can use firstCalldata here
        $http.post('api/userData/init').then(function(newData){
            $state.go('profile');
        });
    })
```